# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname') and The above error occurred in the <Link> component:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router-dom` v6 but I am following an old tutorial. I am getting above mentioned error and I tried many ways but still getting same error.

This is the file which generating error:

```
import React from "react";
import "./sidebar.css";
import logo from "../../images/logo.png";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { TreeView, TreeItem } from "@material-ui/lab";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import PostAddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/PostAdd";
import AddIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Add";
import ImportExportIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ImportExport";

const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
     <div className="sidebar">
      <Link to="/">
        <img src={logo} alt="Ecommerce" />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/admin/dashboard">
        <p>
        Dashboard
        </p>
      </Link>
      <Link>
        <TreeView
          defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          defaultExpandIcon={<ImportExportIcon />}
        >
          <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Products">
            <Link to="/admin/products">
              <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="All" icon={<PostAddIcon />} />
            </Link>

            <Link to="/admin/product">
              <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Create" icon={<AddIcon />} />
            </Link>
          </TreeItem>
        </TreeView>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

Comment: Can you share your routing file also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a `Link` component without a `to` prop wrapping the `TreeView` component. `to` is a required prop.

[Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/link)

> ```
> interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
>     "href"
>   > {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   to: To; // <-- non-optional
>   reloadDocument?: boolean;
> }
> ```

I don't think a link makes sense here so I suggest just removing it.

Example:

```
const Sidebar = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <Link to="/">
        <img src={logo} alt="Ecommerce" />
      </Link>
      <Link to="/admin/dashboard">
        <p>Dashboard</p>
      </Link>
      <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ImportExportIcon />}
      >
        <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Products">
          <Link to="/admin/products">
            <TreeItem nodeId="2" label="All" icon={<PostAddIcon />} />
          </Link>

          <Link to="/admin/product">
            <TreeItem nodeId="3" label="Create" icon={<AddIcon />} />
          </Link>
        </TreeItem>
      </TreeView>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-pathname-and]

If you did actually mean for a `Link` to wrap *all* of that sub-menu then it needs the required `to` prop.